# A proof on the Jacobian and error to prove differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-writing, solution-verification, jacobian

Let $F : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. If there exists an $m \times n$ matrix $A$ and $\rho : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $\forall h \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $F(a+h) = F(a) + Ah + ||h||\rho(h)$, where $\rho(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, then $F$ is differentiable at a.

**My attempt:**
Rearranging yields
$\dfrac{F(a+h) - F(a) - Ah}{||h||} = \rho(h)$, and $\rho(h) \to 0$ means the left hand goes to $0$, and that's the definition of differentiability (if $A$ is the Jacobian).

This almost seems too easy but I feel like I'm missing many details: could someone help me out in filling the missing assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only think is that you also need to prove that $h \mapsto Ah$ is continuous. Which is the case as a linear map defined on a linear space **of finite dimension** is always continuous.

Comment: Why do we need to prove this? I know that it is continuous, but why is this needed?

Comment: This is required by the definition of differentiability. In particular when you define maps between Banach spaces of whatever dimensions. For finite dimensional spaces, all linear maps are continuous. This may be not the case for spaces of infinite dimensions.

Comment: Am I free to just move $F(a) + Ah$ to the other side and divide by $||h||$, something tells me I'm abusing a theorem I don't have?

Comment: You can do that. But you also have to say why $A$ is continuous. It all depends on the definition you were given for the derivative. See [Fréchet derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: The definition of differentiability is often only given for maps between finite dimensional Banach spaces. In those definitions, continuity isn't usually mentioned. The fully general definition for arbitrary Banach spaces is where it's needed, but @qwertburty seems to be working with the less general version.